# Badge notifications open Stack Overflow homepage

Tags: bug, badges, ios-app

Tapping a badge notification in the Stack Exchange app opens the stackoverflow.com homepage. I believe tapping the notification used to take you to the badge page. For example, tapping the "Copy Editor" badge notification would redirect to this page, https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/223/copy-editor.

Is this by design? I usually like to see who else/how many people have the badge when I receive a new one.

In app badge notification:

[image: In app badge notification]

Upon tapping the notification:

[image: Upon tapping the notification]

I am using version 1.5.3 of the Stack Exchange app on an iPhone 6S running iOS 9.3.5.

Comment: The notification is in the app? It looks like the app doesn't have that page, so it redirects you to the mobile version of the site. Which doesn't have that page, and redirects you to the homepage.

Comment: @Cerbrus yes, it is in the app. It used to redirect to the link I posted in my question though.

Comment: This made me more curious about "When will the Sun end all human life on Earth" now :<

Comment: Does it go to the right place if you're signed in on mobile web? Those badges should link to `/users/current?tab=badges`. What I suspect is happening is that because the app doesn't support that page it's opening the browser and since you aren't logged in that page is redirecting to the home page.

Comment: @BrianNickel Ah I see. I'm not normally signed in on my mobile device outside of the Stack Exchange app. I noticed that if I go to my profile>Recent Activity> and then tap on the badge notification in the Stack Exchange app it takes me to the link I mentioned in my question.